# npm run: Executes another (incorrect) script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

This is `scripts` section of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "compile-prebuild": "tsc -p prebuild-tsconfig.json --pretty",
    "prebuild": "ts-node --project PreBuild/tsconfig.json PreBuild/prebuild.ts",

    "testJs": "node test.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "extract-i18n": "ng xi18n Paradise --i18n-format=xlf2 --output-path=i18n --i18n-locale=en && ng run Paradise:xliffmerge"
},
```

The wonderful thing is **when I try `npm run build` or `npm run build -- --prod` another script (`prebuild`) is executed**:

```
> npm run build -- --prod

> project@0.1.1 prebuild ...
> ts-node --project PreBuild/tsconfig.json PreBuild/prebuild.ts
```

Now, if I rename `prebuild` script to `pre-build` (in `package.json`), everything is going to be alright:

```
> npm run build -- --prod

> project@0.1.1 build ...
> ng build "--prod"
...
```

Now, if I reverted to back, the problem appears again!

---

```
> npm -v
6.7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "correct", as it is the documented behaviour of `npm` - see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

> Additionally, arbitrary scripts can be executed by running `npm run-script <stage>`. Pre and post commands with matching names will be run for those as well (e.g. `premyscript`, `myscript`, `postmyscript`).

Generally, scripts can be prefixed with `pre` or `post` to do things before or after a script.

It is best to consider the prefixes `pre` and `post` as reserved when choosing npm script names (unless you intend them to always be run before or after the main task, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The pre and post hooks run automatically by npm. If you have prebuild defined in your package.json, npm will run it automatically when you ask it to run build. Same goes for post hook as well.

You can check out the documentation here. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts